# Why does Visual Studio debugging mode not work properly (performing F5 when F11 was pressed)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition debugger randomly exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310788/why-does-microsoft-visual-c-sharp-2008-express-edition-debugger-randomly-exit)

I've faced the strangest problem with Visual Studio C# debugger in my career. In short, after a break point in my code was hit I cannot step through the code. <kbd>F11</kbd> (step into) and <kbd>F10</kbd> (step over) work for several times, but eventually Visual Studio performs <kbd>F5</kbd> (continue) action. I am still able to debug using break point on every line.

This behavior reproduces on each project developer's machine. It's Visual Studio SP1 everywhere.

I've checked every (as far as I understand) option. I've disabled "Just My Code". I've disabled "step through properties". I've disabled automatic property evaluation. In despair, I've recreated all project and solution files from scratch.

Is there any solution to my problem?

**Update** This behavior could be reproduced only on this project.

**Update 2** This does not seems like threading problem: it reproduces under Visual Studio's developer web server...

Comment: Is this happening in every project you try to debug or only on this one project and/or in one part of the code?  Have you tried creating a simple test project and stepping through it with the debugger?  If it is just in this particular code, post a snippet of where this is occurring.

Comment: It looks like this has been discussed before:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310788/why-does-microsoft-visual-c-2008-express-edition-debugger-randomly-exit> Some of the suggestions in the other topic might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then. It's [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/)'s fault. I've just disabled it and debugger went right.
[NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) generates *SocketException*s if there no mother application running aside. It provokes context switching.

Thank you, Jon Tackabury

Answer (score 3):

This [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/957912) might be interesting for those that find this thread back.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the port of the Visual Studio development server (menu *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Web* -> *Server: User Visual Studio Development Server: Specific port = 49468), and it work fine. Just try that.